# Computing the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Define cummulative distribution function $G(x)$ and $F(x)$ as

\begin{equation}
    G(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      0 & (x<0) \\
      x  & (0 \leq x <1) \\
      1 & (x \geq1)
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    F(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      0 & (x<0) \\
      0.5x  & (0 \leq x <2) \\
      1 & (x \geq 2)
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Then, I want to compute

\begin{equation}
-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[F(x)\ln(F(x))+(1-F(x))\ln(1-F(x))]dG(x)
\end{equation}

My idea is, since $\forall x \in [0,1); dG(x)=dx$ and $\forall x \not\in [0,1); dG(x)=0$ the answer will be

\begin{equation}
-\int_{-0}^{1}[0.5x\ln(0.5x)+(1-0.5x)\ln(1-0.5x)]dx=0.5
\end{equation}

But I didn't learn how to formally calculate the Riemann-Stieltjes integral. Is it correct?

Comment: Yep - the idea is correct (didn't do the integration so won't comment on that).

Comment: @Martin since it's quite tedious, I omitted the integration and just wrote the answer. thx